# Simplify 2D map to optimize pathfinding

Tags: 2d, shortest-path, dijkstra, path-finding, a-star

I'm working on a personal project that requires solving the well-known shortest-path problem.

I have 256x256 tiles maps like the following:

[Example map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7RpM.jpg)

I'm only interested in white (walkable) areas. The rest are either walls or voids on the map.

Running a simple Dijkstra or A-star algorithm produces a path like this one:

[Shortest path on example map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEXtq.jpg)

However, it takes more time than expected. When I draw every visited tile I get these images, depending on the algorithm used:

[Visited tiles while finding shortest path 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBG9s.jpg)

[Visited tiles while finding shortest path 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQOdn.jpg)

I know there is almost infinite research on pathfinding, and that's great unless you don't know where to start. The problem is quite simple, I think. The cost of every arc is simply the Euclidean distance between them. These maps have portals that shorten the path length, but I didn't add them yet. **The path doesn't have to be the shortest one, either, just a reasonable one is fine.**

I noticed that I could break the problem into 3 simpler problems, but to do this I need this kind of modification on the map:

[Simplyfied paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKdm2.jpg)

Now, the walkable areas are the gray ones. Finding the shortest path between any pair of gray points is almost free, even with bare Dijkstra.

The partition of the problem would look like this, when trying to connect points A and B:

1. Find the closest gray point to A. Let's call this point Ag.
2. Find the closest gray point to B. Let's call this point Bg.
3. Find the shortest path for these pair of points: (A-Ag) (Ag-Bg) (Bg-B).
4. The concatenation of these 3 paths are the solution to my problem.

A and Ag should be (almost) linearly reachable to one another, the same with B and Bg. It's possible that the closest gray point to A is on the other side of a wall, so we should find the next closest Ag point. But this is just an idea.

The concrete question is: **Is there an algorithm to make such simplification on the map? or what shortest path algorith would you suggest?**

Thanks!

Comment: The first three images with A*/Dijkstra paths are strange: the first one seems to only have considered diagonal steps. The second one has flooding in one direction but not the other. That can't be right. I'm quite sure you have an error in your code, but without seeing it we cannot help you further on that.

Comment: Hi trincot. Thanks for your response. I've been playing with some heuristics and algorithms. I think the predominance of diagonal steps comes after that diagonal steps cost the same (1) as orthogonal ones, but I use the Euclidean distance (Ed) to choose the next node.
w.r.t flooding only in one direction, again, if you consider only the Ed you can see that the selection of nodes to visit points straight to the target.

Comment: But even then, A* would visit also the horizontal and vertical neighbors. I don't see that in your images. I'm convinced you have a bug in your A* implementation. You say "the selection of nodes to visit points straight to the target", but that is not true. In [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQOdn.jpg) there is a lot going on in the section below the starting point, and there is no good reason why there (going up!!) and not in other directions (going down at every possible point). I really believe you should not (yet) look into the simplifications you suggest, but fix your A* search.